# Ubuntu not recognizing monitor and not charging when switching docking station

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have different docking stations at home and at my office desk.
At home, I have a Lenovo docking station with one external monitor connected, at my office desk, I have a Dell docking station with two external monitors connected.

When I put my laptop into hibernation, disconnect the dockingstation at home and wake it up in the office and connecting the Dell docking station, only one or no display is working.
Also, the laptop does not charge when connected to the dock sometimes.

xrandr shows that all displays are connected, however, one of the external displays has no signal.

When the system is in this state and I put the laptop into hibernation again and wake it up, I got a completely dark screen on my primary display and I have to restart the whole system.

Below is the xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+
   1680x1050     60.03  
   1280x1024     60.03  
   1440x900      60.03  
   1280x800      60.03  
   1280x720      60.03  
   1024x768      60.03  
   800x600       60.03  
   640x480       60.03  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-4 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have installed Ubuntu 23.04 with kernel 6.2.0-20 on a lenovo T14 with Ryzen CPU/ AMD GPU